# Jenkins API - find all jobs using specific GIT repo

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-api

Any idea how I can query jenkins to get list of all jobs running specific GIT repo? Or list of all jobs and the GIT source code they are using?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
import jenkins

repo_name = 'my_repo'
found_jobs = []

server = jenkins.Jenkins(<jenkins-ip>, <username>, <password>)
jobs = server.get_all_jobs()
for job in jobs:
    data = server.get_job_config(job['name']) . # data is xml
    if re.search(r'%s\<\/url\>' %repo_name, data):
        found_jobs.append(job['name'])
```

Basically, I'm just looking in the xml for the pattern: `<url>my-repo-url</url>` and then appending to the list. For me, this was the easiest way without converting from xml to dict or json and then searching that data structure. Having searched hundreds of jobs, it has worked well for my case.

Comment: Another thing to note on this is if you're using Project folders to group builds, you'll need to use `job['fullname']` instead of `job['name']`. When the projects are nested jenkins expects the full path even if the job names are unique.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get specific build # configuration using python:
import json
import urllib

url = 'http://jenkins_user:jenkins_password@my_jenkins_repo.com:8080/job/job_folder/job/job_name/build_number/api/json?pretty=true'

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

print data

with this you can first find all jobs under folder/repo, take last job for each and find the git repo for each job.